# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exist if $a_n = n\sin\Big(\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)$? (angles are in radians)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

We were given this as an assignment in class. Unfortunately, the lesson was not discussed properly. Apparently the answer is 1 but I have no idea how to solve it. I read somewhere that L'Hospital's rule must be used but the instructor didn't discuss that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since
$$a_n=\frac{\sin (1/n)}{1/n}$$
We only need to study the function $\frac {\sin x}{x}$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Did you mean as $x \to 0^{+}$?

Comment: The existence of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is sufficient for the existence of the given limit, but not necessary; think to $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2\pi n)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $t=\frac1n$, then $\frac1t=n$, and we have $t\to 0^+$ as $n\to\infty$. Then you can rewrite the problem as $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sin t}{t}$. Does that help?

Comment: Did you mean as $t \to 0^{+}$?

Comment: Certainly did, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to assess this is to use L'Hospital's rule, as you already observed. Since the limit is an indeterminate form of the $0/0$ variety, you can rewrite
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(1/n)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos(1/n)\cdot(1/n^2)}{1/n^2}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(1/n) \\
&= \cos(\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n) = \cos 0 = 1,
\end{align*}
where we used L'Hospital's rule in the second equality and continuity of $\cos$ in the fourth equality.